# How to fix "manifest merger error" due to the Firebase Database implementation

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-gradle-plugin

I'm coding an 23 API app, and i need to add Firebase Database services. When i add the line

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0`

in the gradle app and i try to sync, it failes showing this:

```
 ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute
 application@appComponentFactory
 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
 [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
 AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91   is also present at
 [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).    Suggestion: add
 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element
 at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-48:19 to override.
```

Can anyone please help me out?

This is my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.QUeM.TreGStore"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    // Glide image library
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'

    //dipendenza per firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

}

//plugin per l'utilizzo di firebase
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: by migration to androidx or by using older firebase version(compatible with support library)

Comment: i don't know what migrating to androidX would involve to my app, but i'd stick with the current structure. I'll try a older version, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0` then you have to do the following:

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019):

> This release is a MAJOR version update and includes breaking changes.
>   With this release, libraries are migrated from the Android Support Libraries to the Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries.
>   The updated libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:
>
> - Upgrade `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to v3.2.1 or later.
> - Upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to 28 or later.
> - Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in Migrating to AndroidX.

To migrate the other dependencies to `androidx` package, you can do the following:

> With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can quickly migrate an existing project to use AndroidX by selecting **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** from the menu bar.

Check this for more info:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate